# How to display result of SQL in jsp?

Tags: java, sql, oracle, jdbc

Below is SQL statement in jsp. As you can see I want to display back my SQL result, but failed to do so. I believe my method is wrong. Please help me.

```
Connection connection = null;
        try{
        Class.forName("oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleDriver");
        connection = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:oracle:thin:@localhost:1521:xe", "system", "oracle");
        Statement statement = connection.createStatement();
        String query ="SELECT COUNT(CATEGORY) AS COUNTER FROM CLASSIFY WHERE CATEGORY='REMEMBER'";
        ResultSet rst =statement.executeQuery(query);

        String counteRemember= rst.getString("COUNT");
        out.println(counteRemember);
        }
        catch(ClassNotFoundException e)
        {
            out.print("error1");
        } 
        catch (SQLException e) 
        {
            out.print("error2");
        }
```

Comment: you got any errors ???

Comment: COUNT(CATEGORY) **AS** COUNTER - Your ResultSet has COUNTER column containing the result of the count.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you call the wrong column(COUNT is the sql function you are calling but not the result column):

```
String counteRemember= rst.getString("COUNT");
```

change it to:

```
if(rst.next()) {
  String counteRemember= rst.getString("COUNTER");

}
```

or:

```
String counteRemember= rst.getString(1);
```

Comment: I think it should be `rst.getString(1);` the indexing starts at `1` for `ResultSet`

Answer (score 0):

Make below changes and try:

```
while(rst.next()){
String counteRemember= rst.getString("COUNTER");//because "COUNT" is not a column name here..
}
```